# QueryDSL build select count query

Tags: java, querydsl

I would like to build select count query by using QueryDSL library, something like this:

`select count(1) from table1`

I created next code:

```
SQLTemplates sqlTemplates = builder.printSchema().build();
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(sqlTemplates);
Path table = new RelationalPathBase(Object.class, "alias", "hr", "table1");
StringPath[] columnsPath = new StringPath[1];
columnsPath[0] = Expressions.stringPath(table, "field1");
SQLQuery sqlQuery = new SQLQuery(dataSource.getConnection(), configuration)
                .from(table);
sqlQuery.setUseLiterals(true);
String selectStatement = sqlQuery.getSQL(columnsPath).getSQL();
```

As result selectStatement is next:

```
select alias.field1 from hr.table1 alias
```

Could please someone advice how to rewrite code above to get

```
select count(alias.field1) from hr.table1 alias
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the last line with

```
String selectStatement = sqlQuery.getSQL(columnsPath[0].count()).getSQL();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough?

```
...from(table).count();
```

Comment: `count()` method return result of query execution but I need text of generated sql query: `select count(1) from table1`